# MySql last entry on revolving table

Tags: mysql

How do I get the last entry into a table based on time? Time is the Key to the table.

It is a revolving 24 hour table that is "supposed" to update every minute.

something like 
select element from table X 
where time is most recent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select element from table X order by time desc limit 1
```